# Get the ID of the default language equivalent page in Polylang

Tags: multi-language, plugin-polylang

How can I get the ID of the default language equivalent for whatever page I’m currently on?

For example, I’m on `abc.com/es/mypage`, I want to get the ID of `abc.com/mypage`.

I tried setting up the variable this way:

```
$englishID = get_the_id(pll_default_language());
```

But this just grabs the ID of the page I’m currently on, not the English equivalent. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe it is a good time to read what is on and off topic here ;)

Comment: Where do I read that? There is even a tag for polylang-plugin, so not sure how this is off-topic

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: There are 50 active Q's with tag plugin-polylang on this forum right now, and they are certainly not being downvoted. If I'm not supposed to talk about a plugin, why is there a tag for it?

Comment: StackExchange at its best. Let's not talk about solutions but rather talk about rules what not to post but then, probably for the sake of search engine optimization, inconsequential still keep that seemingly inappropriate off-topic content and even keep the dumbass comments which couldn't be more off-topic at all.

Answer (score 4):

you can retrieve this identifier with that code :

```
$defaultLanguage = pll_default_language();

$translations = pll_get_post_translations($post_ID);

$id = $translations[$defaultLanguage];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$post_id = pll_get_post( get_the_ID(), pll_default_language() );
```

Got this from the plugin author, works great!